# Prove that if $\alpha$ lies inside an osculating plane at any point, then it has zero torsion.

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

I know in words that torsion is the failure of a curve to remain within a plane so if a point on the curve is within the plane then torsion must be 0.

I also know the osculating plane is $\{x: \langle x-\alpha(t), B(t)\rangle=0 \} $

I do not know how to write this proof mathematically. I tried using the Frenet-Serret theorem but was unable to approach a valid solution.

Comment: This statement isn't quite right: For all $t$, $\alpha(t)$ itself lies in the osculating plane to the curve at $\alpha(t)$, but not all curves in $\Bbb R^3$ have zero torsion.

Answer (score 0):

As was pointed out in the comments, the statement is not quite true. I guess you wanted to ask the following statement: If the curve lies in the osculating plane at some fixed point, then the torsion is zero.

Consider a unit speed curve $\alpha\colon I\subset \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^3$ with positive curvature $\kappa$ and  a point $\alpha(t_0)$, $t_0\in I$, on the curve. The osculating plane at $\alpha(t_0)$ consists of the points $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$ with $\langle x- \alpha(t_0), B(t_0)\rangle=0$.

If $\alpha$ lies in the osculating plane, then $\langle \alpha(t)-\alpha(t_0),B(t_0)\rangle=0$ for all $t\in I$. Deriving this equation twice and using the Frenet formulas gives
$$ 
  \langle T, B(t_0)\rangle = 0 \quad \text{ and }  \quad \langle \kappa N , B(t_0)\rangle =0.
$$
Since we assume $\kappa > 0$, the binormal vector field $B$ is always parallel with $B(t_0)$. So the direction and length of $B(t)$ is constant. Hence $B'=0$, so $-\tau N= 0$ at every point by the Frenet-Serret formulas. This implies that $\tau =0$.